NWConnection and cellular data, isComplete never becomes true
I am using NWconnection to force some requests to go through cellular data. Everything works fine, except I keep calling connection.receive and don't know when the transfer is complete.
// Setting up the connection:
     let tcpOptions = NWProtocolTCP.Options()
     let parameters = NWParameters(tls: .init(), tcp: tcpOptions)
     parameters.requiredInterfaceType = .cellular
     port = port ?? NWEndpoint.Port(443)

// ...

   NWConnection(to: .hostPort(host: NWEndpoint.Host(host),port: port), using: parameters)

//...

    func receive(withConnection connection: NWConnection, completion: @escaping dataCompletion) {
        connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: Int.max) { [self] data, contentContext, isComplete, error in
            if let data = data {                
                receivedData.append(data)                
                print(contentContext)
                if isComplete || error != nil  || connection.state != .ready {                    
                    cancelConnection(connection)
                } else {
                    processor?.receive(withConnection: connection, completion: completion)
                }
            } else {                
                cancelConnection(connection)
            }
        }
    }


I am consuming regular HTTP endpoints. The data in receive comes in chunks but isComplete parameter never becomes true, so I don't know when to stop and send the complete receivedData back.
I've thought of adding a timeout, but it seems kind of hacky. Is there a better solution?

You are likely using HTTP/1.1. These sessions will not automatically close. This is a performance optimization so that the (expensive) connection can be reused. You need to parse the HTTP to determine when the request has completed. See Section 4.4 Message Length for details on how to determine this for different kinds of requests. Generally you will parse the Content-Length field.

Thanks Rob! Yes, I am using HTTP 1.1.   Is the header Content-length reliable enough? (Is it present most of the time?) This will be used with different external services and I would like to find a method to reliably known that the HTTP message was transferred completely.

No; not in the general case. You will need to parse the HTTP headers as described in section 4.4 linked above. In many common cases it will be in Content-Length, but there are other situations where Content-Length is forbidden. Also, keep in mind that for an arbitrary remote service, you may need to deal with HTTP/1.0, though it is very rare. You should also be aware of the move towards HTTP/2. I do not expect many services to become HTTP/2-only in the foreseeable future, but in the general case it is something worth being aware of.
